# Get Windows files associations via Java

Tags: java, windows, registry, associations

I thought this would be an easy task but . . . 
I want my Java program to get the user's Windows file associations.
In other words, I want to know what the user uses to open .txt files, .cvs files, etc.
The assoc and ftype commands provide that info, but not for the user.
In other words, if I've set my text editor to Notepad++, 
assoc and ftype don't show it. They show the system default, Notepad, instead.
It looks like I have to get that info from the registry but I have two problems.
1) I don't know the exact registry keys I want to pull
   (though I've looked at "reg query HKEY_CURRENT_USER, HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, etc.)
2) I don't know how to pull the key from the registry. I've seen JNI mentioned
   but haven't figured out the details.
Any hints appreciated.

Comment: What is it exactly you want to achieve? The [Desktop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html) can open/edit files by opening them in the associated editors for you.  You learn more [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/desktop.html)

Comment: What version of Windows are you using?

Comment: Yes, java.awt.Desktop seems to be what I need. I'm using Windows 7 but want something that's cross-platform.

Answer (score 0):

In Win7, you can find the "class"* for each file extension in the

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\<extension>\(Default)
```

key.

For example, on my machine

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\.txt
```

has a (Default) key of `txtfile`.

In that same path, you can find what opens files of the class `txtfile`:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\txtfile
```

Which should have a subpath of `...\shell\open\command`

On my system,

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\txtfile\shell\open\command\(Default)
```

is

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\NOTEPAD.EXE %1
```

Which you could parse to find the executable that opens .txt files.

For user-specific customizations, you can replace

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\
```

with

```
HKCU\Software\Classes\
```

All that being said, I like MadProgrammer's suggestion if possible for your application.

* I'm sure there is a better name for "class", I just don't know it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Eclipse's Program class, which should to what you want: http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fprogram%2FProgram.html.

If you would like to launch the program, use the Desktop-class (like MadProgrammer suggested)

Comment: It's even more than I was looking for. "Program.launch("c:/trash/a.txt");" launches my preferred text editor. Many thanks!

Comment: However, while Program.launch() works from inside Eclipse it doesn't seem to work from a Jar file. So that's my next task. Any more info appreciated.

Comment: I think you need some initialization before Program can be used. Could you try to instantiate an swt display before you use the program class?

Comment: It seems the Desktop API (java.awt.Desktop) is going to work better for me than SWT.