# How to open a file with a specific programme in Desktop

Tags: java

I am using java.awt.Desktop to open a file. I don't have control over the filetype programme associations and I would like to open a file with a specific programme that is non default. How can I do this?

This is my code:

```
 public static void open(File document) throws IOException {
        Desktop dt = Desktop.getDesktop();
        dt.open(document);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the name and location of the program to execute, you can run it directly, and provide it with the filename to open as an argument (after a space):

```
try {
    Runtime runTime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    // Don't forget that '\' needs to be escaped with another '\'
    // Also, there may be spaces in the name(s). Use quotes (with their own escapes!)
    Process process = runTime.exec("\"C:\\Windows\\system32\\notepad.exe\"" +
                                   " " +    // Separate argument with space
                                   "\""+document.getAbsolutePath()+"\"");
} // try
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} // catch
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the Desktop class supports that; there's no API for querying file associations.

Do you want the user to choose from a list? If so, I think you have to do it per platform. For Windows, you can refer to this question:
[Get Windows files associations via Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13576124/get-windows-files-associations-via-java)

Or do you already have a specific program in mind? If so, then you can launch it directly with Runtime.exec():
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html