# Get application associated with a file java

Tags: java

I am trying to get the associated program of a file, for example
if I have a file `C:/foo/bar.example` I want to get what program
opens `.example` (Kind of like Notepad.exe opens .txt Files).

I tried creating a process to open that file using `runtime.exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler C:/foo/bar.example")`
but there is no way to get the associated application using [Process](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html).

This example shows what I am trying to achieve in Windows, although I want something cross platform.

Comment: Related [How to open user system preferred editor for given file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526037/how-to-open-user-system-preferred-editor-for-given-file), but without a documented way to determine what application was run.

Comment: .example is a Java application? Is it a jar file?

Comment: I don't think there is a general answer for every OS. But maybe the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13576250/11905620) might help you for Windows.

Comment: @MaS does not work for Java 11/12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think that this is possible just using *pure* Java.

The only way that comes to my mind right now (using Java) is to use [JNA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access) to directly interface with the Win32-API (note that this is written in C and not Java). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17773402/7350192) for how to achieve the Win32-API-part and [this link](https://www.techbeamers.com/write-a-simple-jna-program-in-java/) for how to use JNA.